# Problem with tensorflow showing a syntax error when I try to import it into a python script

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

So I'm trying to run an executable Python script in Ubuntu on Windows. When I try to `import tensorflow`, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorFileWriter.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/ksjones/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 291
    from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops import print_v2 as print
```

I am at a loss since it is showing the syntax error inside the code of `tensorflow` itself. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `tensorflow`, and I get the same results. I tried looking into the code of `tensorflow` itself, and found the line in question, and I cannot see anything obviously wrong. I have looked all over the internet and cannot find anybody having the same issue.

Comment: do you have a file or folder named `tensorflow` ? If so, try renaming it

Comment: What version of TF do you use?

Comment: I do not have a folder named tensorflow. I am using version 2.13.1.

Comment: py -m pip install tensorflow[and-cuda] here is link https://pythonguides.com/install-tensorflow/

Comment: Please always include the full traceback, the message is not complete.

Comment: I pasted almost the entire traceback. The only thing missing is a message that just says "Syntax Error."

Comment: The traceback needs to be verbatim, nothing should be missing from it.

Comment: You appear to be executing the code with Python 2, in which `print` is a reserved keyword, not an identifier bound to a built-in function.

Comment: Yes that was my suspicion too, that the code is being executed in python 2.x

Comment: Again, literally the only thing missing from the traceback was "Syntax error: invalid syntax" which since I said that it was giving me a syntax error, was redundant information that would not help anyone actually fix the problem.

Comment: I tried updating the python installation, and it's now giving me a different error. It is telling me that it can't find the distutils module.

Comment: I ran it using python 3.8, which I had already installed, so I don't know why my system was defaulting to python 2. That seemed to fix it. Thanks for pointing out the version difference problem.

Comment: No, running under python 2 would use a different path (not ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages), you were doing something extra to add that path to the python path so it would be found.

Comment: I just ran the script using "python scriptname.py." I was not doing anything extra.